# Recieving Error Viewing Reports in Report Manager

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, reportmanager

I am receiving the following error trying to view a report in Report Manager and Reporting Services:  "

Your browser does not support scripts or has been configured not to allow scripts"  I have ensured that scripting is enabled and added the site to my trusted sites and still does not work.  What am I missing?  I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.  My reports work fine in a test windows application, but not in the browser.
I can see the header and footer of the report and the toolbar, but the body is empty.  It's only when I select view source that I see the error.

Here is the complete error when I View Source:

```
<div>
Your browser does not support scripts or has been configured not to allow scripts.
<span id="ctl31_ReportViewer">
<div id="ctl31" onclick="if ($get('ctl31_ctl04') != null &amp;&amp; $get('ctl31_ctl04').control != null) $get('ctl31_ctl04').control.HideActiveDropDown();" onactivate="if ($get('ctl31_ctl04') != null &amp;&amp; $get('ctl31_ctl04').control != null) $get('ctl31_ctl04').control.HideActiveDropDown();" style="height:100%;width:100%;"></div>
<div id="ctl31_HttpHandlerMissingErrorMessage" style="border-color:Red;border-width:2px;border-style:Solid;padding:10px;display:none;overflow:auto;font-size:.85em;">
   <h2>
      Report Viewer Configuration Error
   </h2>
   <p>The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file.  Add &lt;add verb=&quot;*&quot; path=&quot;Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd&quot; type = &quot;Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, ReportingServicesWebUserInterface, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91&quot; /&gt; to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add &lt;add name=&quot;ReportViewerWebControlHandler&quot; preCondition=&quot;integratedMode&quot; verb=&quot;*&quot; path=&quot;Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd&quot; type=&quot;Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, ReportingServicesWebUserInterface, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91&quot; /&gt; to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.</p>
</div>
<span id="ctl31_ctl03"><input type="hidden" name="ctl31$ctl03$ctl00" id="ctl31_ctl03_ctl00" /><input type="hidden" name="ctl31$ctl03$ctl01" id="ctl31_ctl03_ctl01" /></span><input type="hidden" name="ctl31$ctl10" id="ctl31_ctl10" /><input type="hidden" name="ctl31$ctl11" id="ctl31_ctl11" />
<div id="ctl31_AsyncWait" style="background-color:White;opacity:0.7;position:absolute;display:none;filter:alpha(opacity=70);">
```

I even get these errors in a test web application, even though scripting is enabled and my httpHandlers are defined in my web config for both system.web and system.webserver.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: It was happening in all browsers, I found the problem though.  It was a problem with one of my parameters.  For some reason, the reportviewer for the web doesn't like extra ' marks.